# Почему я не могу установить nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Не как не получается установить nginx
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотели сказать, "запустить", да?

Comment: Покажите `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: sudo nginx -t проверьте

Comment: Разобрался нужно было еще поудалять файлы `sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt install nginx-full, кому даже танцы с бубном не помогают, потом проверить через,sudo ufw app list